# Cut pipe or remove ferrule using tool when replacing compression valve?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, valve, shutoff

I have been changing the valves under my sink and I was wondering what is the best course of action?

- I've attempted to remove the ferrule on two of the pipes and it wouldn't come off. (I had no tool for it). I ended up reusing it with a new valve and had no leaks. Is this going to be okay?
- As an alternative, I cut the other two pipes behind the nut that hugs the ferrule. This made the pipes shorter but I still had about 2-3 fingers of pipe to mount a new ferrule and the rest of the valve. No leaks there either.
- I know also that I could have removed the ferrule using a tool but all of them were too tight. On those that I cut the copper was dented towards its inner part.

I just want to make sure of the correct choice when replacing a compression valve.

Also, I was wondering, what happens when a pipe ends up being too short for a compression valve? Can it be extended using a 1 inch copper pipe sweated on and then add a compression valve?